# Property 'yPos' does not exist on type 'Element'

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, types, htmlcollection

I'm refactoring an old project and converting it from javascript to typescript. In one of my functions I am getting the position of an element using `yPos` (yPos seems to be enabled only after the element is dragged), the intent is to drag it to another position and drop it, but when I try to get the property `yPos` I get this error:

```
Property 'yPos' does not exist on type 'Element'.ts(2339)
```

I receive a `HTMLCollection` with 12 nodes (all `div`) as a parameter, loop over it and get the `yPos` of the actual element:

```
const whereAmI = (nodes: HTMLDivElement) => {

   Array.from(nodes.children).forEach((el, i) => {
      console.log('el.yPos: ', el.yPos)
   })
}
```

In the original code I was using a `for` loop:

```
   for (let i = 0; i < nodes.children.length; i++) {
      const el = nodes.children[i]
      console.log('el.yPos: ', el.yPos)
   }
```

From everything I've read I imagine that maybe I shouldn't be setting `nodes: HTMLDivElement`, but instead using another type, but I couldn't figure out which one. I also think that maybe I should cast `el` with something else, but I couldn't find anything that fits what I need.

Comment: I can't find anything about `yPos` where do you have any documentation about that?

Comment: check your tsconfig.json. what is the option for compilerOptions.target

Comment: @Yilmaz es5. I'm using react.

Comment: @Konrad Linkowski it is quite an old code, but it is enabled after the `onDragStart event`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `yPos` looks like some non-standard property that is set on the nodes directly by not attached code.

In order to make TypeScript aware of that, you can explicitly declare these are `HTMLDivElement`s with the additional property:

```
type DivWithPosition = HTMLDivElement & { yPos: number }

const elWithPosition = el as DivWithPosition

console.log('elWithPosition.yPos: ', elWithPosition.yPos)
```

Please be aware that such `as` casts are somewhat an escape-hatch and basically turn off type checking by trusting the declaration.

Sometimes TypeScript won't accept such casts and will ask to first cast to unknown like that:

```
const elWithPosition = el as unknown as DivWithPosition
```

Suggestion: The standard [data-attribute syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/data-*) might be a better pick to store additional data on HTML elements instead.